# If the coefficients of the y-terms are equal and the coefficients of the x-terms are equal, the graphs of the two lines will be parallel.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

So a student has a claim that for any pair of linear relations, if the coefficients of the y-terms are equal and the coefficients of the x-terms are equal, the graphs of the two lines will be parallel.

For a pair of linear relations the slope has to be the same in both equations, so would an example of this claim being true be

*y = 2x + 7*  and *y = 2x + - 7* ?

Then for an example of the claim being false, I know that the slope of the line must be different than the next to make the lines not parallel.

*Y = 1x + 1* and *Y = -1x + 1*

Are the coefficients of both terms considered equal?

Comment: Since 1 is not equal to -1, I would say they are not considered equal.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Two lines are parallel if and only if they have the same slope. 
       If the line is given in the form $y=mx+b$, the slope is $m$.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it is self-evident that two equations with the same slope will always be parallel. For example $y=2x+7$ is parallel to $y=2x+0.1$, which is parallel to $y=2x+b$, where $b$ is any positive or negative number. So perhaps you could expand a bit on what bothers you with this claim.

Comment: I'm just trying to find two examples that represent the claim, one that is true and one that is false.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the system of equations $$\left\{\begin{eqnarray}ay&=bx+c\\
ay&=bx+c'. \end{eqnarray}\right.$$

Dividing by $a$, we obtain $$\left\{\begin{eqnarray}y&=\frac{b}{a}x+c\\
y&=\frac{b}{a}x+c', \end{eqnarray}\right.$$
which are parallel lines with slope $\frac{b}{a}$. In the second example you've given, you do not have the same value of $b$ for your coefficient on $x$ so the example fails.